# Script to compare and sum two foxpro table

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I Have 2 tables

**Item Table**

```
ItemCode     BatchNumber   Qty
 Item01      Batch1         50
 Item02      Batch2         75
```

**Transaction Table**

```
ItemCode     BatchNumber   QtyUsed
 Item01      Batch1          4
 Item02      Batch2          7
```

**Desired Output**

```
ItemCode     BatchNumber   Qty    QtyUsed   Balance
 Item01      Batch1         50       4       46
 Item02      Batch2         75       7       68
```

What sql script to achieve this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get it for you.   The trick is to pre-query each set so at most you have one record per item / batch combination.  If not, and you have multiple in either table, you will get a Cartesian result.  Starting with the item table, these are guaranteed to have a record, while the transaction table may never have a sale of said item.  This way the item pre-summarized query is done first, then compared to the sum of all transactions having at most a 1:1 ratio of record.  But if no corresponding transactions for an item / batch, the NVL() will return a zero value, but I set to 000000 so if the first record has a null value you don't get a single digit column width answer by only doing null with a single 0.

```
select;
      TmpItem.ItemCode,;
      TmpItem.BatchNumber,;
      TmpItem.SumQ as Qty,;
      cast( NVL( TmpTrans.SumUsed, 0 ) as int) as QtyUsed,;
      TmpItem.SumQ - NVL( TmpTrans.SumUsed, 0 ) as Balance;
   from ;
      ( select ItemCode, BatchNumber, SUM(Qty) as SumQ;
           FROM ItemTable;
           GROUP BY 1, 2 ) TmpItem;
           LEFT JOIN;
           ( select ItemCode, BatchNumber, SUM(QtyUsed) as SumUsed;
                FROM TransTable;
                GROUP BY 1, 2 ) TmpTrans;
           ON TmpItem.ItemCode = TmpTrans.ItemCode;
           AND TmpItem.BatchNumber = TmpTrans.BatchNumber
```

Comment: I think it would be a better approach to cast() the result. i.e.: cast( NVL( TmpTrans.SumUsed, 0 ) as int) as QtyUsed

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way. Combine both tables using a `UNION` statement. This way you have all of your records in one cursor/table. In the second statement you can do your `GROUP BY` to get the totals for `Qty`, `QtyUsed` and `Balance` fields.

Sometimes splitting the work into smaller select statements can make the problem easier to figure out.

```
SELECT i.ItemCode, i.BatchNumber, i.Qty, 0000 as QtyUsed ;
    FROM Item i ;
UNION ;
SELECT t.ItemCode, t.BatchNumber, 0000 as Qty, t.QtyUsed ;
    FROM Transaction t ;
    INTO CURSOR one

SELECT ItemCode, BatchNumber, SUM(Qty) as Qty, SUM(QtyUsed) as QtyUsed, (SUM(Qty) - SUM(QtyUsed)) as Balance ;
    FROM one ;
    INTO CURSOR two ;
    GROUP BY ItemCode, BatchNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
SELECT a.ItemCode, a.BatchNumber, a.Qty
       b.QtyUsed, a.Qty - b.QtyUsed as Balance
  FROM ItemTable a
  LEFT JOIN TransactionTable b ON a.ItemCode = b.ItemCode 
                          and a.BatchNumber = b.BatchNumber
```

Sure if **ItemCode** and **BatchNumber** are distinct